# Enable server-side includes in Apache2 for selected domains

Tags: apache2

I'm running Apache2 (2.4.29-lubuntu4.11) on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I see documentation for enabling server-side includes (SSI) when I google, but it's always done in *httpd.conf* (modern *apache2.conf*), etc. I suspect these are older posts. I manage my domains out of */etc/apache2/sites-available/some-domain.conf* (individual vhost configuration) files and I don't wish to enable server-side includes except for a couple of domains.

Can the effect of enabling SSI be limited to only selected domains?

How is this done specifically? I've tried, for example,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    AddType           text/html .shtml
    AddHandler        server-parsed .shtml
    AddOutputFilter   INCLUDES .shtml
    Options           Includes
</VirtualHost>
```

How do `Options`, `AddType`, `AddHandler`, `AddOutputFilter`, etc., done in *some-domain.conf*, interact with what's in */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*?

Comment: Just saw you haven't accepted my answer to this question. If it worked for you or helped you, I'd appriciate if you could accept it so others can see it too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your . htaccess as well as just enabling it in a container.
For more information please take a look at this documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

> To permit SSI on your server, you must have the following directive
>   either in your httpd.conf file, or in a .htaccess file:
>
> Options +Includes
>
> This tells Apache that you want to permit files to
>   be parsed for SSI directives.

To enable SSI for a specific domain or directory you can also put it in a container inside a virtualhost configuration:

```
<Directory /example/dir>
...
Options ...someOtherOptions... +Includes
...
</Directory>
```

I think your last question (site conf or Apache conf) was already answered [here](https://serverfault.com/a/216260).